# Shrinkwrap modifier creates creases

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have a Subsurface modifier on top of a shrinkwrap modifier. The shrinkwrap modifier seems to create creases whene applied. The creases disappear if I put the shrinkwrap modifier on top of the subsurface modifier but then I don't get the desired shape.

[image: screenshot]

How can I get rid of these creases ?

Comment: What are you shrink-wrapping to? That mesh seems to have pretty poor topology to sit under a *SubSurf* modifier

Comment: The original sculpt gets sharper bumps in some places wich stretches the retopology making it hard to smooth it even by adding more edges. Here is the blend file : https://goo.gl/TnaJ9p

Comment: I found a solution on this forum: blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-271391.html

It's a bug but no fix have been found since.